# Django: Limit the number of returned ManyToMany objects

Tags: django, serialization, manytomanyfield

I am using `django.core.serializers` to serialise my Queryset and then return it as JSON later on.

```
from django.core import serializers
from .models import MyModel

def a_view(request):
    objects = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializers.serialize('json', objects, indent=2, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)
```

Let's say MyModel has `MyModel.data`, which is a `ManyToManyField` that could have thousands of relations. I would like to only get the latest X objects of MyModel.data in this case.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could get all of the objects and use `[:]` to chop off what you don't want. Is that what you mean?

```
MyModel.data.order_by('-id')[5:]
```